# Can I select multiple html elements by id or by class?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have 4 buttons in the html document and I want to change the text content for all of them based on the value of a function. I can do it just for only one at a time, but not for all of them.

I have tried to use getElementById to target the specific elements and separate the ids with a comma but this will not fix the problem.

```
 //This is the only example that will actually change the text content for 
only one of the 4 buttons

randomCapital.then(value => {
                    const btnSelect4Reneder = document.querySelector('#btn1')
                    btnSelect4Reneder.textContent = value
                    console.log(value)
                })
 //This will not fix the problem, none of the buttons will change their text 
content
 randomCapital.then(value => {
                    const btnSelect4Reneder = 
                    document.getElementByClassName('btns')
                    btnSelect4Reneder.textContent = value
                    console.log(value)
                })

 //As expected, this way will not work either
 randomCapital.then(value => {
                    const btnSelect4Reneder = document.querySelector('#btn1, #btn2, #btn3, #btn4')
                    btnSelect4Reneder.textContent = value
                    console.log(value)
                })
```

Comment: you commented about value being random. Can you provide more information about what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: randomCapital will return a value which is a random string from an array. I would like to get this new random value as a text content for each one of the buttons.

Comment: My rep won't allow any votes :) Anyway, thanks a lot for the effort, I've tried it with the callback but it still won't work. I'll try to do it again tomorrow.

Comment: please check the answer again. There is a solution without the callback

Comment: @Kevin B this is NOT a duplicate. The question is actually NOT about selecting multiple elementes, but about how to apply a different value to multiple elements

Comment: The duplicate covers both how to select multiple elements and how to iterate/work with the result.

Comment: I ve just tried it... Still, all of the buttons will get the same text content...

Answer (score 1):

There are a few DOM API functions you can use to get the elements - I generally like to use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). You must pass a valid CSS selector to the function (as described below)

> **Selectors**
>
> A DOMString containing one or more selectors to match against. This
>   string must be a valid CSS selector string; if it's not, a `SyntaxError`
>   exception is thrown. See Locating DOM elements using selectors for
>   more information about using selectors to identify elements. Multiple
>   selectors may be specified by separating them using commas.

For example:

```js
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const clickHandler = e => {
  console.log(`You clicked ${e.target.textContent}`);
  e.target.textContent = e.target.textContent + ' - Clicked!';
  e.target.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
};
nodeList.forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn">Button 3</button>
<button class="btn">Button 4</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

let string = 'New content';

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].innerHTML = string;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">content</button>
<button class="btn">content</button>
<button class="btn">content</button>
<button class="btn">content</button>
```

Comment: This seems to work  and all of the buttons are changed accordingly. The problem is that the value is a random item within an array and in this situation the same value will be displayed for all of the buttons.

Comment: @J.Doe There are id property in each element. And don't you want to control them buy one variable? "I can do it just for only one at a time, but not for all of them"

Comment: @J.Doe I didn't catch the aim. i can write function that returns object of buttons by id, is it ok? Like: `let objs = Select('btn1', btn2, ...); objs.btn1.innerHTML = 'Hello'`.

Comment: The 'value' will be a random capital of a country that is taken from an array of all the capitals. I would like to render 4 different capitals for the user to pick and then process that information further.

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery. Selecting by class is the way to go in this situation, imho

```
$('.btns').text(value)
```

Comment: randomCapital.then(value => {  
                        $('.btns').text(value)
                    })

Comment: This will still not work... should I do anything else? I don't know many things about jQuery or how it is used.

Comment: @J.Doe are you even using jQuery?

Comment: Not to be honest. I'm just trying to learn raw JavaScript first.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

let btnText = ['btn 1', 'btn 2', 'btn 3', 'btn 4'];

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < btnText.length; i++) {
    
    buttons[i].innerHTML = btnText[i];
    
  }
}
```

```html
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
```